# Create html accordion table, but how? (Cannot change the html code - it's generated by the application)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, accordion

I have an application which generates a navigation menu as table. I cannot change the format of the generated table and I cannot add classes or anything else to the navigation table.

I made an Example of the table structure, generated by the application:

```
    <table class="APPLIST">
     <tr >
      <td class="APPNAME">Appname 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="EP">Element</td>
     </tr>
     <tr >
      <td class="EP">Element</td>
     </tr>
     <tr >
      <td class="APPNAME">Appname 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr >
      <td class="EP">Element</td>
     </tr>
     <tr >
      <td class="EP">Element</td>
     </tr>
     <tr >
      <td class="EP">Element</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

The goal ist to get an accordion navigation out of this sample maybe by using jQuery or just Javascript.

I searched the web for an solution. I found a lot of example but nothing worked out with Table-Data. Basically, it should do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/z6rueLuL/)

Anyone any idea? help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change the source html table you can still manipulate it using jquery and css. I copied and modified the jsfiddle you linked to show how you could accomplish this -

```
    $('tr').html(function() {
      //if the td within this tr doesn't have a APPNAME class then hide it 
      if (!$(this).find('td').hasClass('APPNAME')) {
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).addClass('accordion');
      }
    });

    $(".APPLIST tr").click(function() {
      $(this).nextUntil('.accordion').stop(true, true).fadeToggle(500);
    });
```

here is the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrkrwa2d/4/)

here is a working pure js solution [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/964e9jrj/13/)

Comment: well.. I have to admit, this solution works on JSFiddle and is exactly what I am looking for, BUT... this Application generates the code inside an iframe where jQuery seems not accessable. :( is there a plain javascript solution for my problem?

Comment: anything you can do in JQuery can be done in javascript although more often than not it will be a little more tricky to implement. I have updated my answer with a pure JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are looking for, but this code just loops trough all the table rows and appends a new 'accordion panel' to the accordion div. After that just initialize the accordion with `.accordion()`

```js
$('tr').each(function(e) {
  $('#accordion').append('<h3>' + $(this).find('td').text() + '</h3><div>text...</div>');

});
  $('#accordion').accordion();
```

```css
.APPLIST{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<table class="APPLIST">
  <tr>
    <td class="APPNAME">Appname 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="EP">Element</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="EP">Element</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="APPNAME">Appname 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="EP">Element</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="EP">Element</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="EP">Element</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<div id='accordion'></div>
```